# Работа скрипта в разных браузерах

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

В общем есть такой скрипт, листающий страницу по скролу к якорям. Работает в Хроме, но не работает в ОгнеЛисе.

```
var anchors = [];
var currentAnchor = -1;
var isAnimating  = false;

$(function(){

function updateAnchors() {
    anchors = [];
    $('.box').each(function(i, element){
        anchors.push( $(element).offset().top );
    });
}

$('body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if( isAnimating ) {
        return false;
    }
    isAnimating  = true;
    // Increase or reset current anchor
    if( e.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0 ) {
        currentAnchor--;
    }else{
        currentAnchor++;
    }
    if( currentAnchor > (anchors.length - 1) 
       || currentAnchor < 0 ) {
        currentAnchor = 0;
    }
    isAnimating  = true;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: parseInt( anchors[currentAnchor] )
    }, 500, 'swing', function(){
        isAnimating  = false;
    });
});

updateAnchors();   

});
```

Что именно здесь не поддерживает Фокс и чем заменить?

Comment: Какая ошибка в консоли?

Comment: Никаких. Страница скролится в обычном режиме.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16788995/6275986

Answer (score 1):

Событие mousewheel не поддерживается firefox-ом. Используйте альтернативу: DOMMouseScroll для Firefox.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788995/mousewheel-event-is-not-triggering-in-firefox-browser